# How can I access the data within the brackets under test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ı want to access under the test parameter but ı couldnt.Whatever ı did ı cant access the test and couldnt revert them a json file.

```
var axios = require("axios").default;
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather',
  params: {
    q: 'London,uk',
    lat: '0',
    lon: '0',
    callback: 'test',
    id: '2172797',
    lang: 'null',
    units: 'metric',
    mode: 'xml'
  },
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'hidden'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    let query = response.data;
  console.log(query);
  
  
  })
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

When ı print query its giving me something like that

```
test({"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":3.28,"feels_like":2.22,"temp_min":1.83,"temp_max":4.59,"pressure":1018,"humidity":76},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.34,"deg":271,"gust":6.26},"clouds":{"all":7},"dt":1645745380,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2019646,"country":"GB","sunrise":1645685813,"sunset":1645723857},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200})
```

and I cant access the parameter like coord,temp or the other stuff
also data looks like that:

```
data: 'test({"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":3.28,"feels_like":2.22,"temp_min":1.83,"temp_max":4.59,"pressure":1018,"humidity":76},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.34,"deg":271,"gust":6.26},"clouds":{"all":7},"dt":1645745380,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2019646,"country":"GB","sunrise":1645685813,"sunset":1645723857},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200})'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing - **callback: 'test'** from the -

```
params: {
    q: 'London,uk',
    lat: '0',
    lon: '0',
    callback: 'test',  //remove this line
    id: '2172797',
    lang: 'null',
    units: 'metric',
    mode: 'xml'
  }
```

Keep it as follows:

```
params: {
    q: 'London,uk',
    lat: '0',
    lon: '0',
    id: '2172797',
    lang: 'null',
    units: 'metric',
    mode: 'xml'
  }
```

It should work now I guess.